# Draw line on Google map javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

First of all sorry for such a direct question, I want to draw a line in google maps using javascript. I have a Array like as follow, but I don't know how to draw lines for those coordinates.

```
$luxian =   array();
$luxian[0] = "117.82601481119,35.520710018055*117.82749740937,35.523964274812";
$luxian[1] = "117.82755348854,35.524426161498*117.82840903478,35.525907227735*117.82851349195,35.52612885859*117.82862091751,35.526346457302*117.82871425816,35.526519881807*117.82882463423,35.526713633235*117.82912224113,35.527249853019*117.82936083635,35.527637281861*117.8295777657,35.527956257082*117.82959887314,35.527996447758*117.82964460687,35.528084204972*117.82966841963,35.528128503632*117.82972307115,35.52822018494*117.82978582455,35.528310080246*117.82990400261,35.52845177136*117.82999756158,35.528552133698*117.83009598521,35.52865337273*117.83014276143,35.528698800257*117.83023713009,35.528794275308*117.8304918434,35.529042557891*117.83059730198,35.529145761049*117.83070357636,35.529252224087*117.83091342166,35.52945667934*117.83096398997,35.529504574745*117.83109216669,35.52962188705*117.8311392124,35.529657518823*117.83156384486,35.530100799832*117.83166310986,35.530203031533*117.83171693299,35.530255827083*117.83182133704,35.530360013618*117.83198254442,35.530519729401*117.83222192856,35.53075448916*117.83225302898,35.530777944285*117.83224194027,35.530768850646*117.83232256693,35.530865917129*117.83242482361,35.53097193098*117.83253140792,35.531079347389*117.83258821924,35.531138115664*117.83264367753,35.531194422866*117.83275216328,35.531306729475*117.83382351239,35.532295382903*117.83402361954,35.532636823132*117.8347117142,35.533501531193*117.834863828,35.5336629671*117.83535724095,35.534137771158*117.83478511666,35.534520381511*117.83468262976,35.534512504632*117.83433491556,35.534507104583*117.8343349828,35.534581180906";
$luxian[2] = "117.83535724095,35.534137771158*117.83559629285,35.534410974548";
$luxian[3] = "117.83559629285,35.534410974548*117.83642012405,35.534951814146*117.83666409631,35.535215894638*117.83661009513,35.535029265199*117.83697421406,35.535006751517*117.83721201313,35.534985486238*117.83738216649,35.534946507764*117.83769119111,35.534962645599*117.83790232624,35.535032731492*117.83833733476,35.53515361727*117.83868574452,35.535236532202*117.83901199701,35.535327323366*117.83926898551,35.535429761456*117.83951384003,35.535567334115*117.83977308187,35.53572936344*117.83997925535,35.535873370189*117.84063135148,35.536221226176*117.84132305853,35.536508914883*117.84165362919,35.536620910474*117.84214159122,35.536678108372*117.84239978837,35.536666655527*117.84269237452,35.536604251683*117.84293536865,35.536513382065*117.84316644567,35.536411565169*117.84331493548,35.536379730076*117.84359117618,35.536446182241*117.84378236108,35.536554405992*117.84403872953,35.536796786407*117.84413368824,35.536890068161*117.84435993181,35.537066095916*117.84461023856,35.537146063224*117.84487436485,35.537193972907";
$luxian[4] = "117.84487436485,35.537193972907*117.84489839819,35.537399409632*117.84457972167,35.537613521087*117.8443068158,35.537738630212*117.84414232927,35.537820768424*117.84406306015,35.538014052987*117.84415668092,35.538132020099*117.84433218176,35.538257201083*117.84444290125,35.538390371004*117.84443815979,35.538562658433*117.84440928361,35.53872865849*117.84433985952,35.539044894845*117.84438007806,35.539515191067*117.844610709,35.539753303442";
$luxian[5] = "117.84487436485,35.537193972907*117.84513877002,35.537226891961";
$luxian[6] = "117.84513877002,35.537226891961*117.84523526805,35.537180878861*117.84536974707,35.53714981909*117.84553133594,35.537100856933*117.84569970026,35.537037221925*117.84596595686,35.536938874715*117.84621921793,35.536845340461*117.84637649771,35.536786205469*117.84652130912,35.536730846648*117.84673664062,35.536650212889*117.84688310958,35.536611896969*117.84695580646,35.536595851883*117.84716443082,35.536572113327*117.84734702616,35.536556768162*117.84744956024,35.536516240264*117.84752845837,35.536439911459*117.84748626954,35.536290991537*117.84742758311,35.536205036836*117.8473944169,35.536133978291*117.84743203834,35.536024049209*117.84753293418,35.535969676141*117.84765855334,35.535945110868*117.84779126379,35.535955795004*117.84791830728,35.535997403152*117.8480958627,35.536069847075*117.84821152161,35.536115507918*117.84846287651,35.53613755978*117.84862867453,35.536079964334*117.84885916058,35.536105763799*117.84907997791,35.536234103587*117.84924187032,35.536334340163*117.84944338503,35.536405674452*117.84963814285,35.536499783483*117.85007467428,35.53669342636*117.85024856378,35.536796992494*117.8504743388,35.536905483975*117.85097549437,35.536951706347*117.85117624513,35.536966546271*117.85130906904,35.536952636036*117.85158966016,35.536908683333*117.85188332254,35.536873814708*117.85208630121,35.536892000419*117.85232007414,35.537001416332*117.85250792539,35.537097210978*117.85280889733,35.537262025915*117.85320259995,35.537457098306*117.85345983115,35.537581043616*117.85376279819,35.537765392653*117.85388870817,35.537822578699*117.85408773486,35.537858603368*117.8542383579,35.537869444347*117.85439061471,35.53787591167*117.85461059691,35.53790300455*117.85484718596,35.537938878282*117.85506231363,35.537982745573*117.85527446437,35.538029582098*117.85547439854,35.538088693064*117.85571654525,35.538204386538*117.85605366846,35.538362871551*117.85617695685,35.538449677905*117.85637399852,35.538576496191*117.85653782006,35.538651767305*117.85697800494,35.538662776836*117.85739427643,35.538652161115*117.85750829481,35.53866485072*117.85760027977,35.538682638678*117.85778184189,35.538762446755*117.85787168621,35.538818495092*117.85798197282,35.538913394768*117.85816719322,35.539126333838*117.85822742481,35.539238566274*117.85825439211,35.539270295098*117.85832463973,35.53931241152*117.85841064785,35.53932125081*117.85849145716,35.539292154328*117.85859858958,35.539161827983*117.85868232332,35.539039619856*117.85877151206,35.538930369635*117.85891539588,35.538800421872*117.85911461197,35.538759913353*117.85927276864,35.538764617522*117.8597110584,35.538770905842*117.85993429345,35.538761737708*117.86020166804,35.538779130106*117.86042114464,35.538807101849*117.86057800171,35.538832021075*117.86078442169,35.538855214534*117.86103877989,35.538880209039*117.86141759879,35.538891875675*117.86163384893,35.538901524816*117.86189206427,35.538925778045*117.86202636222,35.538950842461*117.86216856333,35.538976602188*117.86225791904,35.538994384646*117.86239714368,35.539037257759*117.86249115211,35.539078026586*117.86253421152,35.53910402551*117.86260644732,35.539167064879*117.86270078761,35.539279720043*117.86274907199,35.539367233365*117.8627889185,35.539463545287*117.86284025098,35.539618032513*117.86289239648,35.539767351154*117.86293578275,35.539861710183*117.86299388204,35.53995884599*117.86306805692,35.540058737778*117.863189418,35.540232031676*117.86326256094,35.540407901542*117.86333102625,35.540520885879*117.86341016614,35.54070100441*117.86356586431,35.54088056115*117.86371203196,35.541063497037*117.86385056859,35.541240019178*117.86397085024,35.541414354996*117.86407914361,35.541587772966*117.86434090636,35.541846821829*117.86448245268,35.542026774444*117.86451165811,35.542098239542*117.86445342563,35.542220119722*117.86439242584,35.542278277685*117.86435432073,35.542343961999*117.86442688693,35.542469862434*117.86450375835,35.542511856345*117.86471119134,35.542601538564*117.86484252389,35.54257513776*117.86502289867,35.542527089667*117.86512101443,35.542538345702*117.86523223862,35.542588466245*117.86529877484,35.542647407282*117.8654040361,35.542743734251*117.86555456297,35.542874354714*117.86562355929,35.542940300506*117.86568574301,35.543007163854*117.86571198245,35.543124780226*117.86569895248,35.5432080077*117.86572407336,35.543281686984*117.86580150951,35.54333148661*117.86590453038,35.543322548088*117.86600071852,35.543281153169*117.86614680084,35.54326040021*117.86622423315,35.543296074873*117.86626245951,35.543402369544*117.86621129266,35.543526631256*117.86617836518,35.543613974853*117.86619154597,35.543774116388*117.86632978028,35.543839754231*117.8663962825,35.543828657565*117.86651320345,35.543801559848*117.86662246488,35.543726554831*117.86669990789,35.543772250269*117.866736755,35.543850611902*117.86676489291,35.543952175149*117.86679003376,35.544056770676*117.86682745685,35.54418829955*117.86686157554,35.544263718114*117.86705220028,35.544396291558*117.86710238339,35.544437530754*117.867339799,35.544389163774*117.86742104253,35.544395972941*117.86750315072,35.54448253228*117.86753540029,35.54462308698*117.86754475014,35.544765916898*117.86755163996,35.54489874829*117.86755169003,35.544989095469*117.86752884122,35.545082532236*117.86741137797,35.545147676572*117.8673091569,35.545165357066*117.86717177657,35.545193915649*117.8670504865,35.545230072846*117.86696735839,35.545258823003*117.86686625046,35.545307394941*117.866707617,35.545337352764*117.86660838268,35.545315069548*117.86643719702,35.545309123565*117.86633308769,35.545337912081*117.86622979004,35.545352574171*117.86608424458,35.545364370679*117.8660111937,35.545357653302*117.86579566076,35.545471457516*117.86585782619,35.545514437887*117.86606935269,35.545550726442*117.86622284944,35.54562806705*117.86636434674,35.545687680357*117.86644342571,35.545747466219*117.86660183862,35.54582849846*117.866756164,35.545905786183*117.8668464104,35.545940416428*117.86701300463,35.546011518844*117.86719134197,35.546117145105*117.86727070448,35.546182864555*117.86737706478,35.546265231826*117.86740625272,35.546301651928*117.86752678956,35.546381609284*117.86764183196,35.546372390005*117.86769198595,35.546353656113*117.867846281,35.546326685992*117.86795969881,35.546330772405*117.86806603845,35.546352877936*117.86815711796,35.546388256631*117.86820132524,35.54646836819*117.86813211279,35.546548746678*117.86800672416,35.546602113731*117.86785654798,35.546697938184*117.86776142577,35.546752689654*117.8676701217,35.546808188205*117.86752375332,35.546872999436*117.86744743224,35.54689948426*117.86734437525,35.546882180903*117.8671398867,35.546816875883*117.86683691086,35.546573265225*117.86677175258,35.546556137536*117.86672269699,35.546578902793*117.86671261512,35.546587204124*117.86671561503,35.546590140305*117.8667085431,35.546622268415*117.86676064964,35.546709334419*117.86684110883,35.546802181941*117.86694528293,35.546891387085*117.86705763481,35.546977470055*117.86723924035,35.547084394475*117.86736958417,35.547160943525*117.8674587523,35.547210487783*117.8676553682,35.5473342246*117.86776066239,35.547470037627*117.86782125682,35.547632089134*117.86787227047,35.547705309816*117.86799254421,35.547803423458*117.86810191271,35.547899271189*117.86818020364,35.548001873402*117.86821322337,35.548074301953*117.86818246061,35.548187135531*117.86803391161,35.548287010961*117.86795600576,35.548459498267*117.86802801061,35.548533179706*117.86804520258,35.548573859873*117.86808640886,35.548672197966*117.86811317376,35.548794107983*117.8681233065,35.548914938577*117.8681394384,35.549040552144*117.86821392981,35.549207241311*117.86825294539,35.549284722368*117.86835033196,35.549433117884*117.86841251901,35.549500169349*117.86858815724,35.549646968034*117.86871661839,35.5497655245*117.86885190346,35.549903220682*117.86895936312,35.549995263088*117.86915380892,35.550096668586*117.86929723974,35.550108051229*117.86948265033,35.550069600858*117.86962936576,35.550104784427*117.86976766569,35.55025730523*117.86981486596,35.550339504565*117.86981680263,35.550433609744*117.86974973987,35.550499608566*117.86960332591,35.550567517124*117.86950489898,35.550610448324*117.86941192885,35.550661421259*117.86936448129,35.550657081001*117.86922544431,35.550758755369*117.86913714648,35.550936603513*117.86911427636,35.551066128131*117.86914813169,35.551236734022*117.86914353836,35.551405825521*117.86911740184,35.551572300125*117.86911743199,35.551701703811*117.86915454271,35.551822064263*117.86923992215,35.551969541007*117.86932502708,35.552109966096*117.86933104985,35.552225972957*117.86917373573,35.552324971363*117.86893406817,35.552372190286*117.8688498259,35.552430048183*117.86881164952,35.552411705812*117.8688127265,35.552341696184*117.86894909264,35.552517343093*117.86913071386,35.552643922101*117.86918199599,35.552754000911*117.86915583369,35.552836646476*117.86904541608,35.55292072869*117.86890909269,35.552983272832*117.86878585631,35.553029582736*117.86874795653,35.55303022466*117.86860535496,35.553022055121*117.8685161931,35.552998600403*117.86830243641,35.553002734122*117.8681500571,35.553182429722*117.86814325432,35.553269624379*117.86818444691,35.553432789503*117.86825343486,35.553498641735*117.86831479495,35.553608838348*117.86830472273,35.553730811269*117.86826465383,35.553811780803*117.86819159759,35.553915003361*117.8681482621,35.55404404142*117.86805012335,35.554150933401*117.86783038588,35.554203955858*117.8677052508,35.554215248941*117.86750679128,35.554311836704*117.86739747973,35.554394741326*117.86727917251,35.554469106719*117.86719794351,35.55456863313*117.86715270385,35.554735389602*117.86714071807,35.554860913015*117.86716689674,35.554994495881*117.86716581565,35.55516134597*117.86713011054,35.555290238408*117.86695646724,35.555382303673*117.86681090227,35.555409068984*117.86662254563,35.555475302512*117.86650043244,35.555600684308*117.8664584592,35.555765472381*117.86629382691,35.556013318836*117.86614773012,35.556217184338*117.86602235015,35.556316546359*117.86586889926,35.556380261799*117.86567348021,35.556384397746*117.8654129311,35.556352899047*117.86523551311,35.556325788538*117.86506709314,35.556321581866*117.8649060358,35.556295275748*117.86476841842,35.556223843049*117.86466323131,35.556066192277*117.86458011716,35.555914443674*117.86448474295,35.555883317349*117.86428446362,35.555917490964*117.86416620753,35.556019607814*117.86401716377,35.556087988252*117.86384469132,35.55605768415*117.86369837915,35.55595618316*117.8635733204,35.555803093598";
$luxian[7] = "117.8635733204,35.555803093598*117.86337961522,35.556119186148*117.86356324229,35.55641955935*117.86387465802,35.556615514908*117.86401905871,35.556877616416*117.86403322556,35.556923252365*117.86419942807,35.557112861516*117.86433266536,35.557251675058*117.86435963521,35.557360322179*117.86418958809,35.557609145396*117.86405414716,35.557854459546*117.86389990436,35.558117397083*117.86378463197,35.558309227086*117.86341594833,35.558770252318*117.86315547188,35.55896871844*117.86299226862,35.559107459601*117.86288792222,35.55917375128*117.86281981006,35.559229223939*117.86274379051,35.559335527905*117.86267049495,35.559445316643*117.86262852153,35.559580167148*117.86258029164,35.559663835867*117.8624642315,35.559768778269*117.86234599472,35.559871571544*117.86227079163,35.559998997942*117.86235901655,35.560137762057*117.86254641032,35.560197853071*117.8627335374,35.56026199409*117.86285582526,35.560376115352*117.86295795275,35.560505699749*117.86307206667,35.560641075966*117.86317718809,35.560792303501*117.86325450576,35.561009018139*117.86320242498,35.561190135471*117.86309504202,35.561364979306*117.8629658735,35.561512996888*117.86277842627,35.561607024266*117.86257220612,35.56164324215*117.86235891852,35.561656473713*117.86207044766,35.561729006704*117.86189989664,35.561897834964*117.861902877,35.561950687445*117.86194809704,35.561925129035*117.86131911834,35.562339729132*117.86094842701,35.562537877726*117.86034983921,35.562806827266*117.8601594949,35.562889437445*117.85995441097,35.563102392329*117.85991407938,35.56321082776";
$luxian[8] = "117.85991407938,35.56321082776*117.85980125598,35.563326853216";
$luxian[9] = "117.85980125598,35.563326853216*117.85953722698,35.563574935473*117.85936757262,35.563733888321*117.85937255228,35.563831818992*117.85947990596,35.5638875667*117.85970667935,35.563958898768*117.85974675638,35.564124404303*117.85956907662,35.564246480915*117.85927803955,35.564294850837*117.85907637752,35.564217162792*117.8589148306,35.564211985386*117.85875124005,35.564311797423*117.8587481811,35.564429816158*117.85897389921,35.564530280502*117.85919159659,35.56464079628*117.85930490523,35.564833470816*117.85930781316,35.565065405423*117.85924847107,35.565367044694*117.85922638363,35.565391294359*117.859067793,35.565491086801*117.85890620881,35.565566897146*117.85881486877,35.565635907816*117.85873355157,35.565730797194*117.85865325809,35.565785676088*117.85853483672,35.565847966*117.85844548589,35.56596692115*117.85834611352,35.566065981028*117.85828686485,35.566180600648*117.85832994362,35.566302118616*117.8584804694,35.566232500002*117.85860996464,35.566094105549*117.85858091118,35.566007437625*117.85853979345,35.565970893247*117.85875248553,35.565998546948*117.85892810769,35.565933596779*117.85908665939,35.565907810975";
$luxian[10] = "117.8635733204,35.555803093598*117.86349485374,35.555738302886";
$luxian[11] = "117.86349485374,35.555738302886*117.86337569672,35.555771374965";
$luxian[12] = "117.86337569672,35.555771374965*117.86330037186,35.555731448339*117.86322203512,35.555693560974*117.86304929625,35.555608001032";
$luxian[13] = "117.86349485374,35.555738302886*117.86356594991,35.555355874953*117.86354714935,35.555321965223*117.86353597784,35.555298253943*117.86351908308,35.555237460563*117.86349074501,35.555168964269*117.86350981393,35.555125558299*117.86352289029,35.55510529634*117.86349891236,35.555061694479*117.86345368202,35.554991269513*117.86343951397,35.554976552385*117.86342970562,35.554970724763*117.86341689969,35.55495381776*117.86340273171,35.554939100307*117.86336350097,35.554951596606*117.86325125212,35.554883477311*117.86323735504,35.554841627212*117.86325832689,35.554764558935*117.86327738997,35.5546687995*117.86326240004,35.55459603969*117.86323432679,35.554453476368*117.86321306225,35.554298879562*117.86324220798,35.554252349117*117.8633443579,35.554119597952*117.8634797435,35.553955166988*117.86359499774,35.554026483888*117.86366093197,35.554030415535*117.86376719184,35.55404189822*117.86389442957,35.554017531072*117.86393665685,35.553972153854*117.86398242968,35.553954122711*117.86403964828,35.553949215071*117.86410776932,35.553968288899*117.86417071065,35.553958138465*117.86419195781,35.553904654601*117.8642633451,35.553878370752*117.86426334415,35.553870503706*117.86427396858,35.553850271872*117.86427696198,35.553818216736*117.86431320312,35.553822562753*117.86433036204,35.553760456797";
$luxian[14] = "117.86442329804,35.553899054951*117.86452363339,35.55395055583";
$luxian[15] = "117.86452363339,35.55395055583*117.8647978804,35.553983437387*117.8650158746,35.553958132326*117.86527003377,35.553847243479";
$luxian[16] = "117.86527003377,35.553847243479*117.86535336958,35.553776185598";
$luxian[17] = "117.86535336958,35.553776185598*117.86538225181,35.553725554192*117.86537625337,35.553704758177*117.86538224677,35.553686490148*117.86538224298,35.553657463378*117.86541439509,35.553604068201*117.86543646701,35.553577684744*117.8654648121,35.553586199105*117.86549561027,35.553595488933*117.86552368161,35.553593155494*117.8655558416,35.553593742339*117.86561089271,35.553573898624*117.86565394248,35.553483707373*117.86574904856,35.553389990804*117.86579046914,35.553340513747*117.86570407115,35.553344031798*117.8656830819,35.553323470075*117.86511972189,35.553136835498*117.86512652869,35.553097395746*117.86505649421,35.553120709352";
$luxian[18] = "117.86505649421,35.553120709352*117.86514560985,35.553125317417";
$luxian[19] = "117.86514560985,35.553125317417*117.86505241089,35.553148984815*117.86503741783,35.553120999951*117.86502542384,35.553101379026*117.86499653339,35.553079844773*117.86498535742,35.553062923951*117.86493820432,35.55301562324*117.86490523049,35.553018293565*117.8648692557,35.55299984875*117.86476704738,35.552898577151*117.86474496885,35.552866898674*117.86473379541,35.552862997776*117.86453458166,35.552777278113*117.864513325,35.552766473227*117.86446726797,35.552736505775*117.86454737482,35.552698143435*117.86450322279,35.552656754479*117.86439803889,35.552648556068*117.86435580454,35.552657051042*117.86419287032,35.55272185848*117.86415962165,35.552688438484*117.86416261156,35.552648244484*117.86406449995,35.552542802285*117.86408438834,35.552530573619*117.86399119241,35.552479040376*117.86394405168,35.552461825234*117.86384485431,35.552363168183*117.86377564942,35.552366615757*117.86373777772,35.552367978947*117.86362441885,35.552283892161*117.86342116617,35.552255071725*117.86338302551,35.552261585156*117.86333289313,35.552245480698*117.86316561105,35.552212046532*117.86305443911,35.552110798519*117.86299204247,35.552056604879*117.86286208062,35.551973512012*117.86295819002,35.551733977395*117.8629611686,35.551656889949*117.86290173716,35.55147378889*117.86286272825,35.551261100822*117.86266329663,35.551156170769*117.86215748558,35.551236064634*117.86206651133,35.551233493092*117.86208230476,35.551217003174*117.86208338545,35.551183077403*117.86210840522,35.551036514951*117.86232875419,35.551007213735*117.86216829792,35.550924477248*117.86209309259,35.550818603359*117.86196395599,35.550703410618*117.86179589874,35.550672010524*117.86161830685,35.550612773995*117.86134699319,35.5504044387*117.86114869767,35.550271350761*117.86118053782,35.550200947881*117.86108436839,35.550074130313*117.86097628181,35.550146859328*117.8609204741,35.550198571253*117.86080231128,35.550257307488*117.86068795202,35.550278819065*117.86076422129,35.550363048662*117.86077109091,35.550571857858*117.86072314367,35.550495412813*117.86073734677,35.550644445505*117.86070738251,35.550604941278*117.86069130749,35.550572316208*117.86067115996,35.550580435746*117.86066407999,35.550579439082*117.86064232034,35.550661912436*117.86068426279,35.550693400705*117.86061429537,35.550736053404*117.86060123034,35.550753578848*117.86060204499,35.550745701242*117.86056202071,35.550754066622*117.86013642307,35.550650773864*117.8599202487,35.550643882111";
$luxian[20] = "117.85593732544,35.565119195748*117.85671580022,35.564618703519";
$luxian[21] = "117.86108436839,35.550074130313*117.8608602359,35.550014310871";
$luxian[22] = "117.8608602359,35.550014310871*117.86082129345,35.550005578398*117.86077309171,35.549992620612*117.86073086892,35.549942147476*117.86065271491,35.549927119399*117.8603676099,35.549861200115*117.86024725282,35.549824963806*117.86006534552,35.549722179982*117.85997985547,35.549718325909*117.85969953052,35.549191006149*117.85957146618,35.549641780074*117.85945028471,35.549522466457*117.85936833538,35.549490317843*117.85938030462,35.549466305314*117.85905087389,35.549298614832*117.85865262945,35.54919454267*117.85867627976,35.549115334127*117.85864471907,35.549146609964*117.85839725461,35.548964555915*117.85833899886,35.54892530373*117.85797104577,35.54887576804*117.85782681229,35.548855567759*117.85755063088,35.548883903015*117.85731256031,35.548913697319*117.85687638213,35.548785839619*117.85673026151,35.548710184466*117.85671339787,35.548718483226*117.85616522408,35.548614485036*117.85579421679,35.548598236286*117.85593807959,35.548551669106*117.85551809121,35.54841205122*117.85527488954,35.548227428317*117.85429408629,35.548172706378*117.85428919211,35.548171657369*117.85423399686,35.54815931295*117.85414617235,35.548132010525*117.85383926993,35.548179778049*117.85357046843,35.548278209596*117.85242537403,35.54806722522*117.8523413489,35.547926082251*117.85212740936,35.547707240558*117.85196650553,35.547587102695*117.85181973319,35.547460356593*117.85173543993,35.547304787662*117.85141695926,35.54712865321*117.85119633698,35.54704015491*117.85102817185,35.546993161611*117.85080240914,35.546897279217*117.84973191523,35.546420215019*117.8495442981,35.546430022356*117.8493406686,35.54643170219*117.84915112414,35.54634458737*117.84897922567,35.546238402878*117.8488632496,35.546119850193*117.84863079429,35.54594049575*117.84824929762,35.545672916968*117.84813543672,35.545409940636*117.84825216117,35.545444467515";
$luxian[23] = "117.84825216117,35.545444467515*117.8485753549,35.545306287014*117.84863617336,35.545334917263*117.84872713257,35.545379755741*117.8488229617,35.545390118277*117.84896766543,35.545414732153*117.84996617762,35.545740080274*117.85008405916,35.545792847613*117.8502796405,35.545897678825*117.85043856108,35.545988779259*117.85060539434,35.546137884238*117.85074123742,35.546220078398*117.85096022662,35.546352088248*117.85206283877,35.546731974502*117.85228191452,35.546881348641*117.85243765652,35.546965386761*117.85257658386,35.547108374616*117.8525956711,35.547249341804*117.8527278191,35.547415681917*117.85294856048,35.547563825759";
$luxian[24] = "117.84825216117,35.545444467515*117.84828116745,35.545379571914";
$luxian[25] = "117.84828116745,35.545379571914*117.84826108762,35.545388561303*117.84814327598,35.545351866727*117.84720514559,35.544840501833*117.8470604403,35.544683783178*117.84685894975,35.544376761406*117.84664005325,35.543983967068*117.84650236858,35.54374414384*117.8457037861,35.542816536213*117.84566383668,35.542691429135*117.8455631832,35.542635459188*117.84552113295,35.54261344676*117.84547311372,35.542586543423*117.84545141243,35.542577569866*117.84543649084,35.542568330955*117.84535756372,35.542550617513*117.84510613535,35.542474902869*117.84510533049,35.54248792529*117.84493690458,35.542431806245*117.84484010384,35.542429764237*117.8447473604,35.542408998508*117.84468661711,35.542394790118*117.84463372851,35.542367025613*117.84444695347,35.542003657851*117.84440816282,35.541971567251*117.84410005698,35.541767431583*117.84407915576,35.541727228725*117.84406395504,35.541698162668*117.8440471092,35.54164223154*117.84402282907,35.541421860315*117.84400597559,35.541355617986*117.84398697492,35.541319758715*117.84422994445,35.541047617784*117.84441426953,35.541013803256*117.84447229508,35.54102449546*117.84484987944,35.54088838652*117.84493032381,35.540769392535*117.84517146154,35.540503809246*117.8452243194,35.540475924546*117.84526633436,35.540452637749*117.8453770088,35.540496709513*117.84538274425,35.54055179475*117.8453976912,35.540594950589*117.84539879941,35.540626968309*117.84547304452,35.540916001568*117.84548614484,35.54103132708*117.84557502552,35.541310597053*117.84559188375,35.541372472722*117.84574393912,35.541627356105*117.84577055577,35.541681366498*117.84578279946,35.541737538124*117.84586243476,35.541981503528*117.8458687097,35.542035500174*117.84602945868,35.542302553701*117.8460555277,35.542347602508*117.84618801269,35.54252454154";
$luxian[26] = "117.84566383668,35.542691429135*117.84618801269,35.54252454154";
$luxian[27] = "117.84618801269,35.54252454154*117.84611131136,35.542617856735*117.84611946241,35.542638750813*117.84619358364,35.542746754908*117.84626033805,35.542786922309*117.84633098935,35.542978753843*117.84650614715,35.543276661702*117.84656881672,35.543283708339*117.84679332403,35.5435253948*117.84679862295,35.54375954036*117.84682440733,35.543777437336*117.847097955,35.543885818694*117.84708984818,35.543940087501*117.84722372662,35.544130726619*117.84722088333,35.544370029654*117.84745346892,35.54444931672*117.84767773326,35.544659878095*117.84824892838,35.544994093971*117.84852831345,35.545155263017";
$luxian[28] = "117.84852831345,35.545155263017*117.8485753549,35.545306287014";
$luxian[29] = "117.8453770088,35.540496709513*117.84497535866,35.539710461427";
$luxian[30] = "117.84497535866,35.539710461427*117.84493292086,35.539554144582";
```

Actually, this array is for path which contains many curves and bends. and I drawn a line successfully on Baidu map. But I don't know how to draw it on google map. I have searched in google. But couldn't find good solution. Once again sorry for blank question , kindly help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: You have an array of 31 items, which seem to be pairs of coordinates, delimited by `*`.  Are you wanting to draw 31 lines, or just one line between all those points?  See this article for how to draw polylines: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polylines

Comment: Actually I have used this Array for Baidu map. kindly go through this link, I was drawn line in baidu map using this same array. http://jjzx.lywww.com/map.php , I would like to draw a same lines in google maps too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over your array, adding each pair of coordinates as a new LatLng, which you then pass as a path to the Polyline constructor.  Something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Draw a polyline given many coordinates</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map { height: 80% }
</style>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>

<script>
    function initialize() {             
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            zoom: 13,
            center: {lat: 35.520710018055, lng: 117.82601481119},
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        $luxian =   [];
        $luxian[0] = "117.82601481119,35.520710018055*117.82749740937,35.523964274812";
        $luxian[1] = "117.82755348854,35.524426161498*117.82840903478,35.525907227735*117.82851349195,35.52612885859*117.82862091751,35.526346457302*117.82871425816,35.526519881807*117.82882463423,35.526713633235*117.82912224113,35.527249853019*117.82936083635,35.527637281861*117.8295777657,35.527956257082*117.82959887314,35.527996447758*117.82964460687,35.528084204972*117.82966841963,35.528128503632*117.82972307115,35.52822018494*117.82978582455,35.528310080246*117.82990400261,35.52845177136*117.82999756158,35.528552133698*117.83009598521,35.52865337273*117.83014276143,35.528698800257*117.83023713009,35.528794275308*117.8304918434,35.529042557891*117.83059730198,35.529145761049*117.83070357636,35.529252224087*117.83091342166,35.52945667934*117.83096398997,35.529504574745*117.83109216669,35.52962188705*117.8311392124,35.529657518823*117.83156384486,35.530100799832*117.83166310986,35.530203031533*117.83171693299,35.530255827083*117.83182133704,35.530360013618*117.83198254442,35.530519729401*117.83222192856,35.53075448916*117.83225302898,35.530777944285*117.83224194027,35.530768850646*117.83232256693,35.530865917129*117.83242482361,35.53097193098*117.83253140792,35.531079347389*117.83258821924,35.531138115664*117.83264367753,35.531194422866*117.83275216328,35.531306729475*117.83382351239,35.532295382903*117.83402361954,35.532636823132*117.8347117142,35.533501531193*117.834863828,35.5336629671*117.83535724095,35.534137771158*117.83478511666,35.534520381511*117.83468262976,35.534512504632*117.83433491556,35.534507104583*117.8343349828,35.534581180906";
        $luxian[2] = "117.83535724095,35.534137771158*117.83559629285,35.534410974548";
        $luxian[3] = "117.83559629285,35.534410974548*117.83642012405,35.534951814146*117.83666409631,35.535215894638*117.83661009513,35.535029265199*117.83697421406,35.535006751517*117.83721201313,35.534985486238*117.83738216649,35.534946507764*117.83769119111,35.534962645599*117.83790232624,35.535032731492*117.83833733476,35.53515361727*117.83868574452,35.535236532202*117.83901199701,35.535327323366*117.83926898551,35.535429761456*117.83951384003,35.535567334115*117.83977308187,35.53572936344*117.83997925535,35.535873370189*117.84063135148,35.536221226176*117.84132305853,35.536508914883*117.84165362919,35.536620910474*117.84214159122,35.536678108372*117.84239978837,35.536666655527*117.84269237452,35.536604251683*117.84293536865,35.536513382065*117.84316644567,35.536411565169*117.84331493548,35.536379730076*117.84359117618,35.536446182241*117.84378236108,35.536554405992*117.84403872953,35.536796786407*117.84413368824,35.536890068161*117.84435993181,35.537066095916*117.84461023856,35.537146063224*117.84487436485,35.537193972907";
        $luxian[4] = "117.84487436485,35.537193972907*117.84489839819,35.537399409632*117.84457972167,35.537613521087*117.8443068158,35.537738630212*117.84414232927,35.537820768424*117.84406306015,35.538014052987*117.84415668092,35.538132020099*117.84433218176,35.538257201083*117.84444290125,35.538390371004*117.84443815979,35.538562658433*117.84440928361,35.53872865849*117.84433985952,35.539044894845*117.84438007806,35.539515191067*117.844610709,35.539753303442";
        $luxian[5] = "117.84487436485,35.537193972907*117.84513877002,35.537226891961";
        $luxian[6] = "117.84513877002,35.537226891961*117.84523526805,35.537180878861*117.84536974707,35.53714981909*117.84553133594,35.537100856933*117.84569970026,35.537037221925*117.84596595686,35.536938874715*117.84621921793,35.536845340461*117.84637649771,35.536786205469*117.84652130912,35.536730846648*117.84673664062,35.536650212889*117.84688310958,35.536611896969*117.84695580646,35.536595851883*117.84716443082,35.536572113327*117.84734702616,35.536556768162*117.84744956024,35.536516240264*117.84752845837,35.536439911459*117.84748626954,35.536290991537*117.84742758311,35.536205036836*117.8473944169,35.536133978291*117.84743203834,35.536024049209*117.84753293418,35.535969676141*117.84765855334,35.535945110868*117.84779126379,35.535955795004*117.84791830728,35.535997403152*117.8480958627,35.536069847075*117.84821152161,35.536115507918*117.84846287651,35.53613755978*117.84862867453,35.536079964334*117.84885916058,35.536105763799*117.84907997791,35.536234103587*117.84924187032,35.536334340163*117.84944338503,35.536405674452*117.84963814285,35.536499783483*117.85007467428,35.53669342636*117.85024856378,35.536796992494*117.8504743388,35.536905483975*117.85097549437,35.536951706347*117.85117624513,35.536966546271*117.85130906904,35.536952636036*117.85158966016,35.536908683333*117.85188332254,35.536873814708*117.85208630121,35.536892000419*117.85232007414,35.537001416332*117.85250792539,35.537097210978*117.85280889733,35.537262025915*117.85320259995,35.537457098306*117.85345983115,35.537581043616*117.85376279819,35.537765392653*117.85388870817,35.537822578699*117.85408773486,35.537858603368*117.8542383579,35.537869444347*117.85439061471,35.53787591167*117.85461059691,35.53790300455*117.85484718596,35.537938878282*117.85506231363,35.537982745573*117.85527446437,35.538029582098*117.85547439854,35.538088693064*117.85571654525,35.538204386538*117.85605366846,35.538362871551*117.85617695685,35.538449677905*117.85637399852,35.538576496191*117.85653782006,35.538651767305*117.85697800494,35.538662776836*117.85739427643,35.538652161115*117.85750829481,35.53866485072*117.85760027977,35.538682638678*117.85778184189,35.538762446755*117.85787168621,35.538818495092*117.85798197282,35.538913394768*117.85816719322,35.539126333838*117.85822742481,35.539238566274*117.85825439211,35.539270295098*117.85832463973,35.53931241152*117.85841064785,35.53932125081*117.85849145716,35.539292154328*117.85859858958,35.539161827983*117.85868232332,35.539039619856*117.85877151206,35.538930369635*117.85891539588,35.538800421872*117.85911461197,35.538759913353*117.85927276864,35.538764617522*117.8597110584,35.538770905842*117.85993429345,35.538761737708*117.86020166804,35.538779130106*117.86042114464,35.538807101849*117.86057800171,35.538832021075*117.86078442169,35.538855214534*117.86103877989,35.538880209039*117.86141759879,35.538891875675*117.86163384893,35.538901524816*117.86189206427,35.538925778045*117.86202636222,35.538950842461*117.86216856333,35.538976602188*117.86225791904,35.538994384646*117.86239714368,35.539037257759*117.86249115211,35.539078026586*117.86253421152,35.53910402551*117.86260644732,35.539167064879*117.86270078761,35.539279720043*117.86274907199,35.539367233365*117.8627889185,35.539463545287*117.86284025098,35.539618032513*117.86289239648,35.539767351154*117.86293578275,35.539861710183*117.86299388204,35.53995884599*117.86306805692,35.540058737778*117.863189418,35.540232031676*117.86326256094,35.540407901542*117.86333102625,35.540520885879*117.86341016614,35.54070100441*117.86356586431,35.54088056115*117.86371203196,35.541063497037*117.86385056859,35.541240019178*117.86397085024,35.541414354996*117.86407914361,35.541587772966*117.86434090636,35.541846821829*117.86448245268,35.542026774444*117.86451165811,35.542098239542*117.86445342563,35.542220119722*117.86439242584,35.542278277685*117.86435432073,35.542343961999*117.86442688693,35.542469862434*117.86450375835,35.542511856345*117.86471119134,35.542601538564*117.86484252389,35.54257513776*117.86502289867,35.542527089667*117.86512101443,35.542538345702*117.86523223862,35.542588466245*117.86529877484,35.542647407282*117.8654040361,35.542743734251*117.86555456297,35.542874354714*117.86562355929,35.542940300506*117.86568574301,35.543007163854*117.86571198245,35.543124780226*117.86569895248,35.5432080077*117.86572407336,35.543281686984*117.86580150951,35.54333148661*117.86590453038,35.543322548088*117.86600071852,35.543281153169*117.86614680084,35.54326040021*117.86622423315,35.543296074873*117.86626245951,35.543402369544*117.86621129266,35.543526631256*117.86617836518,35.543613974853*117.86619154597,35.543774116388*117.86632978028,35.543839754231*117.8663962825,35.543828657565*117.86651320345,35.543801559848*117.86662246488,35.543726554831*117.86669990789,35.543772250269*117.866736755,35.543850611902*117.86676489291,35.543952175149*117.86679003376,35.544056770676*117.86682745685,35.54418829955*117.86686157554,35.544263718114*117.86705220028,35.544396291558*117.86710238339,35.544437530754*117.867339799,35.544389163774*117.86742104253,35.544395972941*117.86750315072,35.54448253228*117.86753540029,35.54462308698*117.86754475014,35.544765916898*117.86755163996,35.54489874829*117.86755169003,35.544989095469*117.86752884122,35.545082532236*117.86741137797,35.545147676572*117.8673091569,35.545165357066*117.86717177657,35.545193915649*117.8670504865,35.545230072846*117.86696735839,35.545258823003*117.86686625046,35.545307394941*117.866707617,35.545337352764*117.86660838268,35.545315069548*117.86643719702,35.545309123565*117.86633308769,35.545337912081*117.86622979004,35.545352574171*117.86608424458,35.545364370679*117.8660111937,35.545357653302*117.86579566076,35.545471457516*117.86585782619,35.545514437887*117.86606935269,35.545550726442*117.86622284944,35.54562806705*117.86636434674,35.545687680357*117.86644342571,35.545747466219*117.86660183862,35.54582849846*117.866756164,35.545905786183*117.8668464104,35.545940416428*117.86701300463,35.546011518844*117.86719134197,35.546117145105*117.86727070448,35.546182864555*117.86737706478,35.546265231826*117.86740625272,35.546301651928*117.86752678956,35.546381609284*117.86764183196,35.546372390005*117.86769198595,35.546353656113*117.867846281,35.546326685992*117.86795969881,35.546330772405*117.86806603845,35.546352877936*117.86815711796,35.546388256631*117.86820132524,35.54646836819*117.86813211279,35.546548746678*117.86800672416,35.546602113731*117.86785654798,35.546697938184*117.86776142577,35.546752689654*117.8676701217,35.546808188205*117.86752375332,35.546872999436*117.86744743224,35.54689948426*117.86734437525,35.546882180903*117.8671398867,35.546816875883*117.86683691086,35.546573265225*117.86677175258,35.546556137536*117.86672269699,35.546578902793*117.86671261512,35.546587204124*117.86671561503,35.546590140305*117.8667085431,35.546622268415*117.86676064964,35.546709334419*117.86684110883,35.546802181941*117.86694528293,35.546891387085*117.86705763481,35.546977470055*117.86723924035,35.547084394475*117.86736958417,35.547160943525*117.8674587523,35.547210487783*117.8676553682,35.5473342246*117.86776066239,35.547470037627*117.86782125682,35.547632089134*117.86787227047,35.547705309816*117.86799254421,35.547803423458*117.86810191271,35.547899271189*117.86818020364,35.548001873402*117.86821322337,35.548074301953*117.86818246061,35.548187135531*117.86803391161,35.548287010961*117.86795600576,35.548459498267*117.86802801061,35.548533179706*117.86804520258,35.548573859873*117.86808640886,35.548672197966*117.86811317376,35.548794107983*117.8681233065,35.548914938577*117.8681394384,35.549040552144*117.86821392981,35.549207241311*117.86825294539,35.549284722368*117.86835033196,35.549433117884*117.86841251901,35.549500169349*117.86858815724,35.549646968034*117.86871661839,35.5497655245*117.86885190346,35.549903220682*117.86895936312,35.549995263088*117.86915380892,35.550096668586*117.86929723974,35.550108051229*117.86948265033,35.550069600858*117.86962936576,35.550104784427*117.86976766569,35.55025730523*117.86981486596,35.550339504565*117.86981680263,35.550433609744*117.86974973987,35.550499608566*117.86960332591,35.550567517124*117.86950489898,35.550610448324*117.86941192885,35.550661421259*117.86936448129,35.550657081001*117.86922544431,35.550758755369*117.86913714648,35.550936603513*117.86911427636,35.551066128131*117.86914813169,35.551236734022*117.86914353836,35.551405825521*117.86911740184,35.551572300125*117.86911743199,35.551701703811*117.86915454271,35.551822064263*117.86923992215,35.551969541007*117.86932502708,35.552109966096*117.86933104985,35.552225972957*117.86917373573,35.552324971363*117.86893406817,35.552372190286*117.8688498259,35.552430048183*117.86881164952,35.552411705812*117.8688127265,35.552341696184*117.86894909264,35.552517343093*117.86913071386,35.552643922101*117.86918199599,35.552754000911*117.86915583369,35.552836646476*117.86904541608,35.55292072869*117.86890909269,35.552983272832*117.86878585631,35.553029582736*117.86874795653,35.55303022466*117.86860535496,35.553022055121*117.8685161931,35.552998600403*117.86830243641,35.553002734122*117.8681500571,35.553182429722*117.86814325432,35.553269624379*117.86818444691,35.553432789503*117.86825343486,35.553498641735*117.86831479495,35.553608838348*117.86830472273,35.553730811269*117.86826465383,35.553811780803*117.86819159759,35.553915003361*117.8681482621,35.55404404142*117.86805012335,35.554150933401*117.86783038588,35.554203955858*117.8677052508,35.554215248941*117.86750679128,35.554311836704*117.86739747973,35.554394741326*117.86727917251,35.554469106719*117.86719794351,35.55456863313*117.86715270385,35.554735389602*117.86714071807,35.554860913015*117.86716689674,35.554994495881*117.86716581565,35.55516134597*117.86713011054,35.555290238408*117.86695646724,35.555382303673*117.86681090227,35.555409068984*117.86662254563,35.555475302512*117.86650043244,35.555600684308*117.8664584592,35.555765472381*117.86629382691,35.556013318836*117.86614773012,35.556217184338*117.86602235015,35.556316546359*117.86586889926,35.556380261799*117.86567348021,35.556384397746*117.8654129311,35.556352899047*117.86523551311,35.556325788538*117.86506709314,35.556321581866*117.8649060358,35.556295275748*117.86476841842,35.556223843049*117.86466323131,35.556066192277*117.86458011716,35.555914443674*117.86448474295,35.555883317349*117.86428446362,35.555917490964*117.86416620753,35.556019607814*117.86401716377,35.556087988252*117.86384469132,35.55605768415*117.86369837915,35.55595618316*117.8635733204,35.555803093598";
        $luxian[7] = "117.8635733204,35.555803093598*117.86337961522,35.556119186148*117.86356324229,35.55641955935*117.86387465802,35.556615514908*117.86401905871,35.556877616416*117.86403322556,35.556923252365*117.86419942807,35.557112861516*117.86433266536,35.557251675058*117.86435963521,35.557360322179*117.86418958809,35.557609145396*117.86405414716,35.557854459546*117.86389990436,35.558117397083*117.86378463197,35.558309227086*117.86341594833,35.558770252318*117.86315547188,35.55896871844*117.86299226862,35.559107459601*117.86288792222,35.55917375128*117.86281981006,35.559229223939*117.86274379051,35.559335527905*117.86267049495,35.559445316643*117.86262852153,35.559580167148*117.86258029164,35.559663835867*117.8624642315,35.559768778269*117.86234599472,35.559871571544*117.86227079163,35.559998997942*117.86235901655,35.560137762057*117.86254641032,35.560197853071*117.8627335374,35.56026199409*117.86285582526,35.560376115352*117.86295795275,35.560505699749*117.86307206667,35.560641075966*117.86317718809,35.560792303501*117.86325450576,35.561009018139*117.86320242498,35.561190135471*117.86309504202,35.561364979306*117.8629658735,35.561512996888*117.86277842627,35.561607024266*117.86257220612,35.56164324215*117.86235891852,35.561656473713*117.86207044766,35.561729006704*117.86189989664,35.561897834964*117.861902877,35.561950687445*117.86194809704,35.561925129035*117.86131911834,35.562339729132*117.86094842701,35.562537877726*117.86034983921,35.562806827266*117.8601594949,35.562889437445*117.85995441097,35.563102392329*117.85991407938,35.56321082776";
        $luxian[8] = "117.85991407938,35.56321082776*117.85980125598,35.563326853216";
        $luxian[9] = "117.85980125598,35.563326853216*117.85953722698,35.563574935473*117.85936757262,35.563733888321*117.85937255228,35.563831818992*117.85947990596,35.5638875667*117.85970667935,35.563958898768*117.85974675638,35.564124404303*117.85956907662,35.564246480915*117.85927803955,35.564294850837*117.85907637752,35.564217162792*117.8589148306,35.564211985386*117.85875124005,35.564311797423*117.8587481811,35.564429816158*117.85897389921,35.564530280502*117.85919159659,35.56464079628*117.85930490523,35.564833470816*117.85930781316,35.565065405423*117.85924847107,35.565367044694*117.85922638363,35.565391294359*117.859067793,35.565491086801*117.85890620881,35.565566897146*117.85881486877,35.565635907816*117.85873355157,35.565730797194*117.85865325809,35.565785676088*117.85853483672,35.565847966*117.85844548589,35.56596692115*117.85834611352,35.566065981028*117.85828686485,35.566180600648*117.85832994362,35.566302118616*117.8584804694,35.566232500002*117.85860996464,35.566094105549*117.85858091118,35.566007437625*117.85853979345,35.565970893247*117.85875248553,35.565998546948*117.85892810769,35.565933596779*117.85908665939,35.565907810975";
        $luxian[10] = "117.8635733204,35.555803093598*117.86349485374,35.555738302886";
        $luxian[11] = "117.86349485374,35.555738302886*117.86337569672,35.555771374965";
        $luxian[12] = "117.86337569672,35.555771374965*117.86330037186,35.555731448339*117.86322203512,35.555693560974*117.86304929625,35.555608001032";
        $luxian[13] = "117.86349485374,35.555738302886*117.86356594991,35.555355874953*117.86354714935,35.555321965223*117.86353597784,35.555298253943*117.86351908308,35.555237460563*117.86349074501,35.555168964269*117.86350981393,35.555125558299*117.86352289029,35.55510529634*117.86349891236,35.555061694479*117.86345368202,35.554991269513*117.86343951397,35.554976552385*117.86342970562,35.554970724763*117.86341689969,35.55495381776*117.86340273171,35.554939100307*117.86336350097,35.554951596606*117.86325125212,35.554883477311*117.86323735504,35.554841627212*117.86325832689,35.554764558935*117.86327738997,35.5546687995*117.86326240004,35.55459603969*117.86323432679,35.554453476368*117.86321306225,35.554298879562*117.86324220798,35.554252349117*117.8633443579,35.554119597952*117.8634797435,35.553955166988*117.86359499774,35.554026483888*117.86366093197,35.554030415535*117.86376719184,35.55404189822*117.86389442957,35.554017531072*117.86393665685,35.553972153854*117.86398242968,35.553954122711*117.86403964828,35.553949215071*117.86410776932,35.553968288899*117.86417071065,35.553958138465*117.86419195781,35.553904654601*117.8642633451,35.553878370752*117.86426334415,35.553870503706*117.86427396858,35.553850271872*117.86427696198,35.553818216736*117.86431320312,35.553822562753*117.86433036204,35.553760456797";
        $luxian[14] = "117.86442329804,35.553899054951*117.86452363339,35.55395055583";
        $luxian[15] = "117.86452363339,35.55395055583*117.8647978804,35.553983437387*117.8650158746,35.553958132326*117.86527003377,35.553847243479";
        $luxian[16] = "117.86527003377,35.553847243479*117.86535336958,35.553776185598";
        $luxian[17] = "117.86535336958,35.553776185598*117.86538225181,35.553725554192*117.86537625337,35.553704758177*117.86538224677,35.553686490148*117.86538224298,35.553657463378*117.86541439509,35.553604068201*117.86543646701,35.553577684744*117.8654648121,35.553586199105*117.86549561027,35.553595488933*117.86552368161,35.553593155494*117.8655558416,35.553593742339*117.86561089271,35.553573898624*117.86565394248,35.553483707373*117.86574904856,35.553389990804*117.86579046914,35.553340513747*117.86570407115,35.553344031798*117.8656830819,35.553323470075*117.86511972189,35.553136835498*117.86512652869,35.553097395746*117.86505649421,35.553120709352";
        $luxian[18] = "117.86505649421,35.553120709352*117.86514560985,35.553125317417";
        $luxian[19] = "117.86514560985,35.553125317417*117.86505241089,35.553148984815*117.86503741783,35.553120999951*117.86502542384,35.553101379026*117.86499653339,35.553079844773*117.86498535742,35.553062923951*117.86493820432,35.55301562324*117.86490523049,35.553018293565*117.8648692557,35.55299984875*117.86476704738,35.552898577151*117.86474496885,35.552866898674*117.86473379541,35.552862997776*117.86453458166,35.552777278113*117.864513325,35.552766473227*117.86446726797,35.552736505775*117.86454737482,35.552698143435*117.86450322279,35.552656754479*117.86439803889,35.552648556068*117.86435580454,35.552657051042*117.86419287032,35.55272185848*117.86415962165,35.552688438484*117.86416261156,35.552648244484*117.86406449995,35.552542802285*117.86408438834,35.552530573619*117.86399119241,35.552479040376*117.86394405168,35.552461825234*117.86384485431,35.552363168183*117.86377564942,35.552366615757*117.86373777772,35.552367978947*117.86362441885,35.552283892161*117.86342116617,35.552255071725*117.86338302551,35.552261585156*117.86333289313,35.552245480698*117.86316561105,35.552212046532*117.86305443911,35.552110798519*117.86299204247,35.552056604879*117.86286208062,35.551973512012*117.86295819002,35.551733977395*117.8629611686,35.551656889949*117.86290173716,35.55147378889*117.86286272825,35.551261100822*117.86266329663,35.551156170769*117.86215748558,35.551236064634*117.86206651133,35.551233493092*117.86208230476,35.551217003174*117.86208338545,35.551183077403*117.86210840522,35.551036514951*117.86232875419,35.551007213735*117.86216829792,35.550924477248*117.86209309259,35.550818603359*117.86196395599,35.550703410618*117.86179589874,35.550672010524*117.86161830685,35.550612773995*117.86134699319,35.5504044387*117.86114869767,35.550271350761*117.86118053782,35.550200947881*117.86108436839,35.550074130313*117.86097628181,35.550146859328*117.8609204741,35.550198571253*117.86080231128,35.550257307488*117.86068795202,35.550278819065*117.86076422129,35.550363048662*117.86077109091,35.550571857858*117.86072314367,35.550495412813*117.86073734677,35.550644445505*117.86070738251,35.550604941278*117.86069130749,35.550572316208*117.86067115996,35.550580435746*117.86066407999,35.550579439082*117.86064232034,35.550661912436*117.86068426279,35.550693400705*117.86061429537,35.550736053404*117.86060123034,35.550753578848*117.86060204499,35.550745701242*117.86056202071,35.550754066622*117.86013642307,35.550650773864*117.8599202487,35.550643882111";
        $luxian[20] = "117.85593732544,35.565119195748*117.85671580022,35.564618703519";
        $luxian[21] = "117.86108436839,35.550074130313*117.8608602359,35.550014310871";
        $luxian[22] = "117.8608602359,35.550014310871*117.86082129345,35.550005578398*117.86077309171,35.549992620612*117.86073086892,35.549942147476*117.86065271491,35.549927119399*117.8603676099,35.549861200115*117.86024725282,35.549824963806*117.86006534552,35.549722179982*117.85997985547,35.549718325909*117.85969953052,35.549191006149*117.85957146618,35.549641780074*117.85945028471,35.549522466457*117.85936833538,35.549490317843*117.85938030462,35.549466305314*117.85905087389,35.549298614832*117.85865262945,35.54919454267*117.85867627976,35.549115334127*117.85864471907,35.549146609964*117.85839725461,35.548964555915*117.85833899886,35.54892530373*117.85797104577,35.54887576804*117.85782681229,35.548855567759*117.85755063088,35.548883903015*117.85731256031,35.548913697319*117.85687638213,35.548785839619*117.85673026151,35.548710184466*117.85671339787,35.548718483226*117.85616522408,35.548614485036*117.85579421679,35.548598236286*117.85593807959,35.548551669106*117.85551809121,35.54841205122*117.85527488954,35.548227428317*117.85429408629,35.548172706378*117.85428919211,35.548171657369*117.85423399686,35.54815931295*117.85414617235,35.548132010525*117.85383926993,35.548179778049*117.85357046843,35.548278209596*117.85242537403,35.54806722522*117.8523413489,35.547926082251*117.85212740936,35.547707240558*117.85196650553,35.547587102695*117.85181973319,35.547460356593*117.85173543993,35.547304787662*117.85141695926,35.54712865321*117.85119633698,35.54704015491*117.85102817185,35.546993161611*117.85080240914,35.546897279217*117.84973191523,35.546420215019*117.8495442981,35.546430022356*117.8493406686,35.54643170219*117.84915112414,35.54634458737*117.84897922567,35.546238402878*117.8488632496,35.546119850193*117.84863079429,35.54594049575*117.84824929762,35.545672916968*117.84813543672,35.545409940636*117.84825216117,35.545444467515";
        $luxian[23] = "117.84825216117,35.545444467515*117.8485753549,35.545306287014*117.84863617336,35.545334917263*117.84872713257,35.545379755741*117.8488229617,35.545390118277*117.84896766543,35.545414732153*117.84996617762,35.545740080274*117.85008405916,35.545792847613*117.8502796405,35.545897678825*117.85043856108,35.545988779259*117.85060539434,35.546137884238*117.85074123742,35.546220078398*117.85096022662,35.546352088248*117.85206283877,35.546731974502*117.85228191452,35.546881348641*117.85243765652,35.546965386761*117.85257658386,35.547108374616*117.8525956711,35.547249341804*117.8527278191,35.547415681917*117.85294856048,35.547563825759";
        $luxian[24] = "117.84825216117,35.545444467515*117.84828116745,35.545379571914";
        $luxian[25] = "117.84828116745,35.545379571914*117.84826108762,35.545388561303*117.84814327598,35.545351866727*117.84720514559,35.544840501833*117.8470604403,35.544683783178*117.84685894975,35.544376761406*117.84664005325,35.543983967068*117.84650236858,35.54374414384*117.8457037861,35.542816536213*117.84566383668,35.542691429135*117.8455631832,35.542635459188*117.84552113295,35.54261344676*117.84547311372,35.542586543423*117.84545141243,35.542577569866*117.84543649084,35.542568330955*117.84535756372,35.542550617513*117.84510613535,35.542474902869*117.84510533049,35.54248792529*117.84493690458,35.542431806245*117.84484010384,35.542429764237*117.8447473604,35.542408998508*117.84468661711,35.542394790118*117.84463372851,35.542367025613*117.84444695347,35.542003657851*117.84440816282,35.541971567251*117.84410005698,35.541767431583*117.84407915576,35.541727228725*117.84406395504,35.541698162668*117.8440471092,35.54164223154*117.84402282907,35.541421860315*117.84400597559,35.541355617986*117.84398697492,35.541319758715*117.84422994445,35.541047617784*117.84441426953,35.541013803256*117.84447229508,35.54102449546*117.84484987944,35.54088838652*117.84493032381,35.540769392535*117.84517146154,35.540503809246*117.8452243194,35.540475924546*117.84526633436,35.540452637749*117.8453770088,35.540496709513*117.84538274425,35.54055179475*117.8453976912,35.540594950589*117.84539879941,35.540626968309*117.84547304452,35.540916001568*117.84548614484,35.54103132708*117.84557502552,35.541310597053*117.84559188375,35.541372472722*117.84574393912,35.541627356105*117.84577055577,35.541681366498*117.84578279946,35.541737538124*117.84586243476,35.541981503528*117.8458687097,35.542035500174*117.84602945868,35.542302553701*117.8460555277,35.542347602508*117.84618801269,35.54252454154";
        $luxian[26] = "117.84566383668,35.542691429135*117.84618801269,35.54252454154";
        $luxian[27] = "117.84618801269,35.54252454154*117.84611131136,35.542617856735*117.84611946241,35.542638750813*117.84619358364,35.542746754908*117.84626033805,35.542786922309*117.84633098935,35.542978753843*117.84650614715,35.543276661702*117.84656881672,35.543283708339*117.84679332403,35.5435253948*117.84679862295,35.54375954036*117.84682440733,35.543777437336*117.847097955,35.543885818694*117.84708984818,35.543940087501*117.84722372662,35.544130726619*117.84722088333,35.544370029654*117.84745346892,35.54444931672*117.84767773326,35.544659878095*117.84824892838,35.544994093971*117.84852831345,35.545155263017";
        $luxian[28] = "117.84852831345,35.545155263017*117.8485753549,35.545306287014";
        $luxian[29] = "117.8453770088,35.540496709513*117.84497535866,35.539710461427";
        $luxian[30] = "117.84497535866,35.539710461427*117.84493292086,35.539554144582";

        var path = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $luxian.length; i++) {
            // split this array element into another array, delimited on the *
            var subluxian = $luxian[i].split("*");

            for (var j = 0; j < subluxian.length; j++) {
                // now split it into the lat and lng
                var coords = subluxian[j].split(",");
                // add the coords into the path
                path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[1]), parseFloat(coords[0])));
            }
        }
        var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: path,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            geodesic: true,
            map: map
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You could probably amend it to also zoom to fit the bounds of your path.

Answer (score 2):

Change the map constructor to that defined in the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#google.maps.Map)

Change all your BMap.Point(longitude,latitude) objects to google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude) objects (changing the order of the arguments)

Remove all the calls to map.addOverlay, add the "map" property to the google.maps.Polyline constructor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
body, html,#allmap {width: 100%;height: 100%;overflow: hidden;margin:0;}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<title>??</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

// ????API??

function initialize() {
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(35.520,117.826);
       var mapOptions = {
               zoom: 12,
               center: point,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN}; 

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("allmap"),mapOptions);

var points0=[new google.maps.LatLng(35.520710018055,117.82601481119),new google.maps.LatLng(35.523964274812,117.82749740937)];
var polyline0 = new google.maps.Polyline( {map: map,path:points0,strokeColor:"blue", strokeWeight:6, strokeOpacity:0.5});
var points1=[new google.maps.LatLng(35.524426161498,117.82755348854),new google.maps.LatLng(35.525907227735,117.82840903478),new google.maps.LatLng(35.52612885859,117.82851349195),new google.maps.LatLng(35.526346457302,117.82862091751),new google.maps.LatLng(35.526519881807,117.82871425816),new google.maps.LatLng(35.526713633235,117.82882463423),new google.maps.LatLng(35.527249853019,117.82912224113),new google.maps.LatLng(35.527637281861,117.82936083635),new google.maps.LatLng(35.527956257082,117.8295777657),new google.maps.LatLng(35.527996447758,117.82959887314),new google.maps.LatLng(35.528084204972,117.82964460687),new google.maps.LatLng(35.528128503632,117.82966841963),new google.maps.LatLng(35.52822018494,117.82972307115),new google.maps.LatLng(35.528310080246,117.82978582455),new google.maps.LatLng(35.52845177136,117.82990400261),new google.maps.LatLng(35.528552133698,117.82999756158),new google.maps.LatLng(35.52865337273,117.83009598521),new google.maps.LatLng(35.528698800257,117.83014276143),new google.maps.LatLng(35.528794275308,117.83023713009),new google.maps.LatLng(35.529042557891,117.8304918434),new google.maps.LatLng(35.529145761049,117.83059730198),new google.maps.LatLng(35.529252224087,117.83070357636),new google.maps.LatLng(35.52945667934,117.83091342166),new google.maps.LatLng(35.529504574745,117.83096398997),new google.maps.LatLng(35.52962188705,117.83109216669),new google.maps.LatLng(35.529657518823,117.8311392124),new google.maps.LatLng(35.530100799832,117.83156384486),new google.maps.LatLng(35.530203031533,117.83166310986),new google.maps.LatLng(35.530255827083,117.83171693299),new google.maps.LatLng(35.530360013618,117.83182133704),new google.maps.LatLng(35.530519729401,117.83198254442),new google.maps.LatLng(35.53075448916,117.83222192856),new google.maps.LatLng(35.530777944285,117.83225302898),new google.maps.LatLng(35.530768850646,117.83224194027),new google.maps.LatLng(35.530865917129,117.83232256693),new google.maps.LatLng(35.53097193098,117.83242482361),new google.maps.LatLng(35.531079347389,117.83253140792),new google.maps.LatLng(35.531138115664,117.83258821924),new google.maps.LatLng(35.531194422866,117.83264367753),new google.maps.LatLng(35.531306729475,117.83275216328),new google.maps.LatLng(35.532295382903,117.83382351239),new google.maps.LatLng(35.532636823132,117.83402361954),new google.maps.LatLng(35.533501531193,117.8347117142),new google.maps.LatLng(35.5336629671,117.834863828),new google.maps.LatLng(35.534137771158,117.83535724095),new google.maps.LatLng(35.534520381511,117.83478511666),new google.maps.LatLng(35.534512504632,117.83468262976),new google.maps.LatLng(35.534507104583,117.83433491556),new google.maps.LatLng(35.534581180906,117.8343349828)];
var polyline1 = new google.maps.Polyline( {map: map,path:points1,strokeColor:"blue", strokeWeight:6, strokeOpacity:0.5});
var points2=[new google.maps.LatLng(35.534137771158,117.83535724095),new google.maps.LatLng(35.534410974548,117.83559629285)];
var polyline2 = new google.maps.Polyline( {map: map,path:points2,strokeColor:"blue", strokeWeight:6, strokeOpacity:0.5});
var points3=[new google.maps.LatLng(35.534410974548,117.83559629285),new google.maps.LatLng(35.534951814146,117.83642012405),new google.maps.LatLng(35.535215894638,117.83666409631),new google.maps.LatLng(35.535029265199,117.83661009513),new google.maps.LatLng(35.535006751517,117.83697421406),new google.maps.LatLng(35.534985486238,117.83721201313),new google.maps.LatLng(35.534946507764,117.83738216649),new google.maps.LatLng(35.534962645599,117.83769119111),new google.maps.LatLng(35.535032731492,117.83790232624),new google.maps.LatLng(35.53515361727,117.83833733476),new google.maps.LatLng(35.535236532202,117.83868574452),new google.maps.LatLng(35.535327323366,117.83901199701),new google.maps.LatLng(35.535429761456,117.83926898551),new google.maps.LatLng(35.535567334115,117.83951384003),new google.maps.LatLng(35.53572936344,117.83977308187),new google.maps.LatLng(35.535873370189,117.83997925535),new google.maps.LatLng(35.536221226176,117.84063135148),new google.maps.LatLng(35.536508914883,117.84132305853),new google.maps.LatLng(35.536620910474,117.84165362919),new google.maps.LatLng(35.536678108372,117.84214159122),new google.maps.LatLng(35.536666655527,117.84239978837),new google.maps.LatLng(35.536604251683,117.84269237452),new google.maps.LatLng(35.536513382065,117.84293536865),new google.maps.LatLng(35.536411565169,117.84316644567),new google.maps.LatLng(35.536379730076,117.84331493548),new google.maps.LatLng(35.536446182241,117.84359117618),new google.maps.LatLng(35.536554405992,117.84378236108),new google.maps.LatLng(35.536796786407,117.84403872953),new google.maps.LatLng(35.536890068161,117.84413368824),new google.maps.LatLng(35.537066095916,117.84435993181),new google.maps.LatLng(35.537146063224,117.84461023856),new google.maps.LatLng(35.537193972907,117.84487436485)];
var polyline3 = new google.maps.Polyline( {map: map,path:points3,strokeColor:"blue", strokeWeight:6, strokeOpacity:0.5});
// etc rest of your points 
}
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="allmap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_jjzx_lywww_com_map.html)

**code snippet:** (removing some data so will fit in the answer)

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function initialize() {
  var point = new google.maps.LatLng(35.520, 117.826);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: point,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("allmap"), mapOptions);

  var points0 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5207100, 117.826014), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5239642, 117.827497)];
  var polyline0 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points0,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points1 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5244261, 117.827553), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5259072, 117.828409), new google.maps.LatLng(35.526128, 117.828513), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5263464, 117.828620), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5265198, 117.828714), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5267136, 117.828824), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5272498, 117.829122), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5276372, 117.829360), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5279562, 117.82957), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5279964, 117.829598), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5280842, 117.829644), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5281285, 117.829668), new google.maps.LatLng(35.528220, 117.829723), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5283100, 117.829785), new google.maps.LatLng(35.528451, 117.829904), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5285521, 117.829997), new google.maps.LatLng(35.528653, 117.830095), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5286988, 117.830142), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5287942, 117.830237), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5290425, 117.83049), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5291457, 117.830597), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5292522, 117.830703), new google.maps.LatLng(35.529456, 117.830913), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5295045, 117.830963), new google.maps.LatLng(35.529621, 117.831092), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5296575, 117.83113), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5301007, 117.831563), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5302030, 117.831663), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5302558, 117.831716), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5303600, 117.831821), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5305197, 117.831982), new google.maps.LatLng(35.530754, 117.832221), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5307779, 117.832253), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5307688, 117.832241), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5308659, 117.832322), new google.maps.LatLng(35.530971, 117.832424), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5310793, 117.832531), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5311381, 117.832588), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5311944, 117.832643), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5313067, 117.832752), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5322953, 117.833823), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5326368, 117.834023), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5335015, 117.83471), new google.maps.LatLng(35.53366, 117.8348), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5341377, 117.835357), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5345203, 117.834785), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5345125, 117.834682), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5345071, 117.834334), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5345811, 117.83433)];
  var polyline1 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points1,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points2 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5341377, 117.835357), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5344109, 117.835596)];
  var polyline2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points2,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points3 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5344109, 117.835596), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5349518, 117.836420), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5352158, 117.836664), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5350292, 117.836610), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5350067, 117.836974), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5349854, 117.837212), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5349465, 117.837382), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5349626, 117.837691), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5350327, 117.837902), new google.maps.LatLng(35.535153, 117.838337), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5352365, 117.838685), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5353273, 117.839011), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5354297, 117.839268), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5355673, 117.839513), new google.maps.LatLng(35.535729, 117.839773), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5358733, 117.839979), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5362212, 117.840631), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5365089, 117.841323), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5366209, 117.841653), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5366781, 117.842141), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5366666, 117.842399), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5366042, 117.842692), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5365133, 117.842935), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5364115, 117.843166), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5363797, 117.843314), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5364461, 117.843591), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5365544, 117.843782), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5367967, 117.844038), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5368900, 117.844133), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5370660, 117.844359), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5371460, 117.844610), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5371939, 117.844874)];
  var polyline3 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points3,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points4 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5371939, 117.844874), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5373994, 117.844898), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5376135, 117.844579), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5377386, 117.84430), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5378207, 117.844142), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5380140, 117.844063), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5381320, 117.844156), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5382572, 117.844332), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5383903, 117.844442), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5385626, 117.844438), new google.maps.LatLng(35.538728, 117.844409), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5390448, 117.844339), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5395151, 117.844380), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5397533, 117.8446)];
  var polyline4 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points4,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points5 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5371939, 117.844874), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5372268, 117.845138)];
  var polyline5 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points5,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points8 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.563210, 117.859914), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5633268, 117.859801)];
  var polyline8 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points8,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points10 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5558030, 117.86357), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5557383, 117.863494)];
  var polyline10 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points10,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points11 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5557383, 117.863494), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5557713, 117.863375)];
  var polyline11 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points11,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points12 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5557713, 117.863375), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5557314, 117.863300), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5556935, 117.863222), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5556080, 117.863049)];
  var polyline12 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points12,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points14 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5538990, 117.864423), new google.maps.LatLng(35.553950, 117.864523)];
  var polyline14 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points14,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points15 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.553950, 117.864523), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5539834, 117.86479), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5539581, 117.86501), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5538472, 117.865270)];
  var polyline15 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points15,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points16 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5538472, 117.865270), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5537761, 117.865353)];
  var polyline16 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points16,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points18 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5531207, 117.865056), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5531253, 117.865145)];
  var polyline18 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points18,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points20 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5651191, 117.855937), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5646187, 117.856715)];
  var polyline20 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points20,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points21 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5500741, 117.861084), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5500143, 117.86086)];
  var polyline21 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points21,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points24 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5454444, 117.848252), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5453795, 117.848281)];
  var polyline24 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points24,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points26 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5426914, 117.845663), new google.maps.LatLng(35.542524, 117.846188)];
  var polyline26 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points26,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points27 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.542524, 117.846188), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5426178, 117.846111), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5426387, 117.846119), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5427467, 117.846193), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5427869, 117.846260), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5429787, 117.846330), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5432766, 117.846506), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5432837, 117.846568), new google.maps.LatLng(35.54352, 117.846793), new google.maps.LatLng(35.543759, 117.846798), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5437774, 117.846824), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5438858, 117.8470), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5439400, 117.847089), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5441307, 117.847223), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5443700, 117.847220), new google.maps.LatLng(35.544449, 117.847453), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5446598, 117.847677), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5449940, 117.848248), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5451552, 117.848528)];
  var polyline27 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points27,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points28 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5451552, 117.848528), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5453062, 117.84857)];
  var polyline28 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points28,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points29 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5404967, 117.84537), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5397104, 117.844975)];
  var polyline29 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points29,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points30 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5397104, 117.844975), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5395541, 117.844932)];
  var polyline30 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points30,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points31 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5395541, 117.844932), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5394440, 117.844905), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5393880, 117.844891), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5394179, 117.844830), new google.maps.LatLng(35.539535, 117.844760), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5398308, 117.844710), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5400489, 117.844707), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5402449, 117.844713), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5403980, 117.844769), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5405290, 117.844721), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5406406, 117.844474), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5406464, 117.84436), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5404609, 117.844167), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5403058, 117.844120), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5401717, 117.844098), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5400585, 117.844021), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5398197, 117.843728), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5394937, 117.843369)];
  var polyline31 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points31,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points32 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5395541, 117.844932), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5398855, 117.84470)];
  var polyline32 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points32,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points34 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5349145, 117.83629), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5349518, 117.836420)];
  var polyline34 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points34,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points35 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5239642, 117.827497), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5244261, 117.827553)];
  var polyline35 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points35,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points36 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5659257, 117.857279), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5655762, 117.855778)];
  var polyline36 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points36,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points37 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5391649, 117.844678), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5389347, 117.844509), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5385443, 117.844369), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5382240, 117.844060), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5380037, 117.843830), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5378234, 117.843770), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5376033, 117.843650), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5374630, 117.843441), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5373527, 117.843212), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5372821, 117.843052)];
  var polyline37 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points37,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points38 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5654301, 117.858924), new google.maps.LatLng(35.56545, 117.858780), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5655217, 117.858410), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5653716, 117.858016), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5655210, 117.857915), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5657681, 117.857837), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5659186, 117.857546), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5659257, 117.857279)];
  var polyline38 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points38,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points39 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5654910, 117.8590), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5654301, 117.858924)];
  var polyline39 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points39,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points41 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5558784, 117.863289), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5557713, 117.863375)];
  var polyline41 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points41,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points42 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5630003, 117.859429), new google.maps.LatLng(35.563210, 117.859914)];
  var polyline42 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points42,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points43 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5630003, 117.859429), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5635749, 117.859537)];
  var polyline43 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points43,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points44 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5660636, 117.849938), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5661666, 117.849531), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5661628, 117.849533), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5659250, 117.849434), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5658725, 117.849484), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5659017, 117.849700), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5657690, 117.849791), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5657273, 117.849764), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5656695, 117.849702), new google.maps.LatLng(35.565596, 117.849731)];
  var polyline44 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points44,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points45 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.565596, 117.849731), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5653975, 117.85044)];
  var polyline45 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points45,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points47 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5650864, 117.854618), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5651451, 117.854420)];
  var polyline47 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points47,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points48 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5630003, 117.859429), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5630584, 117.859415)];
  var polyline48 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points48,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points49 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5630584, 117.859415), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5629598, 117.858939), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5630820, 117.858739), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5633482, 117.858537), new google.maps.LatLng(35.563597, 117.858236), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5636665, 117.857945), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5635849, 117.857617), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5635649, 117.857224), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5636572, 117.856885), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5637175, 117.856743), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5638922, 117.856778), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5640165, 117.85695), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5642296, 117.857038), new google.maps.LatLng(35.564322, 117.856966), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5644596, 117.856931), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5646187, 117.856715)];
  var polyline49 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points49,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
  var points50 = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.5655762, 117.855778), new google.maps.LatLng(35.565555, 117.855676), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5655621, 117.855588), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5655406, 117.855537), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5654930, 117.855415), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5654373, 117.855265), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5653564, 117.855050), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5652370, 117.854777), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5650864, 117.854618), new google.maps.LatLng(35.565391, 117.854888), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5654131, 117.854870), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5652083, 117.855049), new google.maps.LatLng(35.565254, 117.85522), new google.maps.LatLng(35.565166, 117.855486), new google.maps.LatLng(35.5651191, 117.855937)];
  var polyline50 = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    path: points50,
    strokeColor: "blue",
    strokeWeight: 6,
    strokeOpacity: 0.5
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
body,
html,
#allmap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="allmap"></div>
```

Comment: Hello geocodezip, if you don't mind can you give me your working example code ? sorry, if I ask something wrong.

Comment: Actually, I was tried a way you mentioned and Mr. duncan mentioned. but the problem is, I also getting some unwanted lines too, in fact, there are many unwanted lines are showing, I couldn't find out where it's making problem. I hope, there is something wrong with my LatLang,. But your working example sample http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_jjzx_lywww_com_map.html contains exactly what I looking for. if you don't mind can you mail me that html file alone. please .

Comment: View:source on the page in your browser and save it to your computer (please remove my analytics id from it before publishing it on the web).

Comment: Hi geocode. I'm having another problem of offline map. I hope you may across that problem or you may know the answer. kindly look at this link please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085785/google-maps-offline-map-api-3-infowindow

Comment: Using the Google Maps Javascript API v3 offline is against the terms of use (at least last I read them), consult with your lawyer (IANAL).

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, if there is a legal issue sure I will not use it. Actually, I'm working on tourist guide based project for Android. In china, google native android map on Android is not working properly so I just doing it by google java script API. and I'm working map for some mountain area. in that Mountain there is poor network and sometimes no network too. kindly advise me what shall I do in such a case.